# How many combinations of ordered even and odd numbers exist that equal some integer?

Tags: arithmetic

Suppose we have $$x_1 < ... < x_{10}$$ where each $x_i \in \Bbb N$. Specifically, suppose $$x_1,...,x_5 \in 2\Bbb N$$ and $$x_6,...,x_{10} \in 2\Bbb N+1$$

Let $$\sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i = 271$$.

How many possible combinations of $(x_1,...,x_{10})$ are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider counting solutions of
$$x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{10}=271$$
as counting arrangements of $271$ identical dots in a row, with $9$ lines to separate them into the $10$ values $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{10}$.  To count these arrangements, consider that there are $280$ available positions, and you have to choose $9$ positions to take the lines.  The answer to this problem is $C(280,9)$.

**BUT** in your case you have the additional condition that $x_1,\ldots,x_5$ are even and $x_6,\ldots,x_{10}$ are odd.  So, set aside $5$ dots - you now have $266$ dots.  Consider these as pairs of dots - you have $133$ pairs.  Now arrange these $133$ pairs and $9$ lines in a row as above - there are $C(142,9)$ ways of doing so.  Now take your $5$ reserved dots and put one into each of the last five spots - this ensures that $x_1,\ldots,x_5$ are even and $x_6,\ldots,x_{10}$ are odd.  Hence:

**answer**: $C(142,9)$.